# Vue 2.7.14 + Vite: imported component renders properly locally, but as <!----> in production

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vite

## Background

I have a page that imports various components, e.g., a settings sidebar, a scatter plot, etc.

I load the components as follows:

```
  export default defineComponent({
    components: {
      ClickToEdit: () => import('@/components/form/ClickToEdit.vue'),
      PlaceRankSettings: () => import('@/views/placerank/components/PlaceRankSettings.vue'),
      LoadingPanel: () => import('@/components/form/LoadingPanel.vue'),
      ...
    },
```

In the template, I use the settings as follows:

```
          <PlaceRankSettings
            :loading="loading"
            @select="updateViewMode"
          />
```

## Problem

Everything works fine locally using `vite`, but when I do `vite build`, the settings component is rendered as `<!---->`.

I have tried wrapping the import in `async/await`, `defineAsyncComponent`, etc., but nothing has worked.

Also, all of the other components get rendered properly.

Any ideas on why that one settings component does not get rendered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. A child component is importing vue-slider-component, and there is an open issue involving Vite and Rollup: https://github.com/NightCatSama/vue-slider-component/issues/642.

## Solution

The solution is to add `requireReturnsDefault: true` to `vite.config.js`:

```
export default defineConfig({
  // ...{ otherOptions }
  build: {
    commonjsOptions: {
       requireReturnsDefault: true,
    },
  },
})
```